# How to disable the Android Studio Profile

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

As we all know, from android studio 3.0 with gradle plugin 3.0, the android studio provides the 'Profile', I want to disable it, because I found it modify my class bytecode during compiling, we can found the corresponding implement codes here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_3.0.0/profiler.

From the above implement code, I found the http profile switch is stored in this file 'System.getProperty("android.profiler.properties")', you can find the detail in thie link https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_3.0.0/profiler/transform/src/main/java/com/android/tools/profiler/ProfilerTransform.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F

how can i access this file to disable the http profile